# Equivalence of set of minimizers of different optimization problems

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

Let $N = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ denote a set of items, $s \in \mathbb N^N$ the size of each item, $x \in \{0, 1\}^N$ a decision variable indicating whether item $i \in N$ is part of a package and $C > 0$ a capacity.
I am wondering whether the following relationship holds:
\begin{align}
\arg\min_{x} |C -  s \cdot x| = \arg\min_{x} (C -  s \cdot x)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Suppose not, and obtain a contradiction by showing that an optimal solution for one side provides a better than optimal solution for the other side.